# Not able to initialise choice fields in Unit test for django form where choice field is getting populated from db

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms

I have one django form where a choice field is getting populated from db.

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
   CLASS_CHOICE = []
   classes = Class.objects.filter(std__gte=4)
   for cls in classes:
     CLASS_CHOICE.append((cls.code,
                               "{} - {}".format(cls.code,cls.std)))
   name = forms.CharField()
   class = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CLASS_CHOICE)

   def _post_clean(self):
     # some validation
     pass
```

When writing its unit test as:

```
class SampleTest(TestCase):

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
      super(SampleTest, cls).setUpClass()
      cls.class = Class.objects.create(std=10,code='A')

   def test_valid_form(self):
      post_data = {'name':'testing',
                   'class':'A' }
      f = TestForm(data=post_data)
      self.assertTrue(f.is_valid())
```

Now the problem is, when running test, the application is loaded first before initializing db hence the `setUpClass` for unit test is not getting called and `CLASS_CHOICE` remains blank and form validation is getting failed. How can I avoid this or reinitialize choice field after i create one entry in `Class` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it set up the class choices are only going to be populated once, when the module containing your code is executed for the first time. This is less than ideal because:

- if new classes are added they will not be available as choice options
- the database may not be connected when this module is loaded into memory, causing runtime errors

You need to make it so that `choices` is built dynamically every time a new form is created. To do this make `choices` a callable function rather than a list:

```
def get_class_choices():
    class_choice = []
    classes = Class.objects.filter(std__gte=4)
    for cls in classes:
        class_choice.append((cls.code, "{} - {}".format(cls.code, cls.std)))
    return class_choice


class TestForm(forms.Form):

   name = forms.CharField()
   class = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_class_choices)

   def _post_clean(self):
     # some validation
     pass
```